# Conflict with relationship and foreign key 1-1

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-key-relationship

I'm trying to do this relationship

```
 public class Company {
      public int Id { get; set; }

      public Configuration Configuration { get; set; }
 }

 public class Configuration {
      public int Id { get; set; }

      // public int CompanyId { get; set; } -> can't do this

      public Company Company { get; set; }
 }

 public class ConfigurationMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Configuration> {
      public ConfigurationMapping {
           HasRequired(configuration => configuration.Company)
                .WithOptional(company => company.Configuration)
                // .HasForeignKey(configuration => configuration.CompanyId) -> this doesn't exist
                .Map(f => f.MapKey("CompanyId")); // that's why I can't use the property above
      }
 }
```

I can't understand how I can add a `Configuration` and set the `IdCompany`.
There's another approach?
How can I do this?

```
db.Configurations.Add(new Configuration {
    IdCompany = idCompany
});
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. One-to-one relation is currently supported only if dependent entity has FK to principal entity as its primary key. It means that `Configuration.Id` is PK of `Configuration` but also FK to `Company.Id`.

The reason why you cannot use `CompanyId` is that database would require it to use unique index (otherwise it would not be one-to-one relation but one-to-many) and EF currently doesn't support unique indexes.

Edit:

Sorry. Now I better understand your question. If you know the Id of the company and you want to add it a new configuration you can try to do something like this:

```
var company = new Company { Id = companyId }; 
context.Companies.Attach(company);  // Existing company, EF know thinks it was loaded from DB

var configuration = new Configuration { Company = company }; // Create relation with existing company. It must not be related to other configuration!
context.Configurations.Add(configuration);
```

Comment: Understood, but how can I set a value to Company? I must retrieve the company and set configuration.Company = company?

Comment: I added some example. It works without any problem for one-to-many scenarios so I hope it will work for one-to-one as well.